# How to use onCall with aws-sdk-mock?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mocking, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I would like let the mock method enable different responses for consecutive calls to the same method.

I found that Sinon has onCall, it allowed I can stub method like below,

```
        let stubCall = sandbox.stub(Math, 'random');
        stubCall.onCall(0).returns(Promise.resolve(0));
        stubCall.onCall(1).returns(Promise.resolve(-1));
```

but I don't know how to let this work on AWS mock framework like this.

```
        AWS.mock('CloudFormation', 'describeStacks', Promise.resolve(stackResponse));
```

I tried

```
AWS.mock('CloudFormation', 'describeStacks', Promise.resolve(stackResponse)).onCall(0).returns(Promise.resolve(res));
```

and

```
let mockCall = AWS.mock('CloudFormation', 'describeStacks', Promise.resolve(res));
mockCall.onCall(0).returns(Promise.resolve(res));
```

both of them didn't work.

I found people [discuss this issue](https://github.com/dwyl/aws-sdk-mock/issues/93) , mentioned since this aws-mock use sinon, it should able to use onCall. Is anyone use it successfully?

Since I use promise, I don't know what else I can do to return the different response for the same method has been called several times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### First, set the AWS SDK instance to be mocked

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const AWS_Mock = require('aws-sdk-mock');
const AWS_SDK = require('aws-sdk');

AWSMock.setSDKInstance(AWS_SDK);
```

#### Configure stub that will be called

```
const stub = sinon.stub();
stub.onCall(0).returns(1);
stub.onCall(1).returns(2);
```

#### Mock Service method

Make sure that you're mocking the exact signature of the method.

```
AWSMock.mock('CloudFormation', 'describeStacks', function(params, cb) {
  cb(null, stub());
});
```

#### Our Mocked method in action

```
const cf = new AWS_SDK.CloudFormation();

cf.describeStacks({}, (err, data) => {
  if(err) {
    console.err(err);
  }
  console.log(data); // 1
});

cf.describeStacks({}, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.err(err);
  }
  console.log(data); // 2
});
```

Comment: Can you make multiple mocks to same method with different arguments? Lets say I want to use a mock that is called multiple times with one argument. Then also have a mock that handles other requests with another argument.

Comment: Sure. See the `withArgs` and `callsFake` functions  https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/